# How can I reference a companion object's method in a generic class?

Tags: scala, generics

So I am a bit new to scala.

How does one write scala code to reference a method from case class's companion object in a generic fashion?  I have tried a couple of different approaches and can't seem to find one that works.

Below is some sample code that works, but I have to manually build each subclass.

For example:

```
class One extends Act[LetterA] {
    val intro = LetterA.sayhi
}
```

I would much rather do something like:

```
class AllOfThem[T <: LettersClass, S <: LettersSingleton] extends Act[T] {
   val intro = S.sayhi
}
```

but I can't seem to find syntax that works or will compile.  What is the proper way to do this, or am I looking for something that is not supported in the language?  I recognise I am probably a little off on how I am structuring my classes and traits, but I am not sure how to best tackle this desired behaviour.

Additionally, is there a way to something similar to what I have commented out in the method 'actionTwo' in the Act class?

Sample Code listing:

```
trait LettersSingleton {
   def sayhi() : String
}

trait LettersClass {
   val id : Int
}

// trait Letters extends LettersClass with LettersSingleton {  }


object LetterA extends LettersSingleton {
   def sayhi = "Hi I am A"
}

object LetterB extends LettersSingleton {
   def sayhi = "Hi I am B"
}

case class LetterA( val id : Int ) extends LettersClass { }
case class LetterB( val id : Int, val name:String ) extends LettersClass { }


abstract class Act[ T <: LettersClass ]  {

   val intro : String

   def actionOne( a : T ) = {
       println( a.id + " is my id" )
   }

   def actionTwo() = {
//       println( T.sayhi )
   }
}

class One extends Act[LetterA] {
    val intro = LetterA.sayhi
}

class Two extends Act[LetterB] {
    val intro = LetterB.sayhi
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't do *exactly* what you want, but you can get very close with the commonly used typeclass pattern:

```
//add a type parameter, now you have a typeclass
trait LettersSingleton[T] {
   def sayhi() : String
}

//LettersClass stays the same

object Implicits {
  //implicit classes/objects have to go inside an object

  //create typeclass instances as implicit objects
  implicit object LetterASingleton extends LettersSingleton[LetterA] {
     def sayhi = "Hi I am A"
  }

  implicit object LetterBSingleton extends LettersSingleton[LetterB] {
     def sayhi = "Hi I am B"
  }
}

import Implicits._

//add an implicit parameter to the class
abstract class Act[ T <: LettersClass ](implicit singleton: LettersSingleton[T])  {

   def actionTwo() = {
       println( singleton.sayhi )
   }
}

(new Act[LetterA]).actionTwo() //prints "Hi I am A"
(new Act[LetterB]).actionTwo() //prints "Hi I am B"
```

So basically what happens is any time you create a new `Act[T]`, the compiler is going to try to fill in the implicit parameter for you by looking for any implicit objects or vals of the correct type in scope.  So

```
val a = new Act[LetterA]
```

will actually become

```
val a = new Act[LetterA](LetterASingleton)
```

You'll notice that the singletons are no longer the companion objects of the case classes, which is fine.  You have to define a trait regardless, so it doesn't make much different whether it's the companion object or some other object that implements it.